# error in sonata media bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

i installed sonata admin bundle as giving in document 
mine issue is i am getting this error on clearing cache

---

Runtime Notice: Declaration of Sonata\MediaBundle\Controller\MediaAdminController::render() should be compatible with Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::render($view, array $parameters = Array, Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response = NULL)

here is my composer.json req

```
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.4.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "2.3.*@stable",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "~0.11",

    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.2",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",

    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "~2.0",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.3.2"
```

i tired everything but still no clue why i am getting this error please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using sonata media 2.3 with sonata admin 2.4 : [github issue](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/issues/731)

Change all reference to the 2.4 verson to 2.3. You can set for example : `~2.3.0`

Comment: it work's & from next time i ll spend more time on config file